# converting between Biginit & Long & Int64 is it safe

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a column inside sql server 2008 r2 of type `Biginit`, and when i map the sql server table using entity framework, it automatically assign the Biginit a `long` datatype. my question is weather such conversion is correct or should be overridden ? in other words is SQL server 2008 Biginit 100% equivalent to .Net Long ?
second question is .Net Long 100% equivalent to .Net Int64 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For .Net

The internal .Net datatype is `Int64`. This is a 64 bit signed integer. `long` is an alias for `Int64`. Probably because it looks more C#-ish.

### For SQL

`BigInt` is also a 64bit signed integer. It is essentially the same (has the same domain/range) as other signed 64-bit integer types. With one exception, `BigInt` can have a null value, and has this behavior by default.

So actually:

- `BigInt` = `long?` = `Nullable<long>`
- `BigInt NOT NULL` = `long`

Answer (score 3):

SQL's `bigint` is equivalent to C#'s `Int64`.

`long` is just syntactic sugar for `Int64`, same as `string` and `String` or `int` and `Int32`.

So `bigint == long == Int64`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SQL server `BigInt` = .NET `Int64` = C# `long`